Why is scale out instance count metric not working on Azure app services?
We have configured ALL metrics on an app service, but when trying to view all instance count metrics, there is no data. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?
Please see the images below. The plan is definitely scaling out, I have verified the run history manually. However, on the app service the metric is showing no data.



What is your App Service plan?

@Harshitha I have added some images to the body of the question for more clarity, can you take a look?

I scaled out the App Service Plan and successfully viewed the instance count metrics in my App Service.
Please refer to this doc for a better understanding of scaling out the App Service Plan and its metrics.
After creating Azure App Service.

Open Scale Out (App Service plan) in the menu bar of the app service - > select scale out method as rules based - > Hit configure



Then select custom autoscale and click on add rule.



Now add the below details in your scale rule and hit add


After referring to the documentation and applying the above configurations, I can now see the metrics in my App Service.

